# add class to regex jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this

```
if( window.location.href == "http://localhost:3000/categories") {
     $("#container ul #all_categories a.categories-menu").css("font-weight","bold");
    }   
});
```

but I have a url with:

```
http://localhost:3000/username/boards
```

**username** is dynamic username e.g.

```
http://localhost:3000/michael-21/boards
http://localhost:3000/Richard_10/boards
http://localhost:3000/Mary.50/boards
```

and change for each user.

How can do the same functionality but with this last url?

Thank you

Comment: Your selector doesn't need multiple IDs, this will work and probably be faster (ever so slightly): `$("#all_categories .categories-menu")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a RegEx. The following method is easier, and is also easier to maintain (you don't have to change the URL in the code when moving the page to the production environment):

```
location.pathname.indexOf('/boards', 1) !== -1
```

The previous would also match `/me/not/boards`. If you don't want that:

```
var index = location.pathname.indexOf('/boards', 1);
index !== -1 && location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/', index-1) === 0
```

Finally, the RegEx method:

```
/^\/[^/]+\/boards/.test(location.pathname)
```

#### Implementation example

```
    if( /^\/[^/]+\/boards/.test(location.pathname) ) {
         $("#container ul #all_categories a.categories-menu").css("font-weight","bold");
    }   
});
```

Comment: Can you write a example for this url `http://localhost:3000/michael-gray/boards` with conditional and add class? Thank you Rob W

Comment: Wouu @RobW works fine. Thank you very much!. excuse me for my delay in answering. Thank you again :). How could works for http://localhost:3000 or http://localhost, or any domain index, without any path after .com domain? Thank you!