# add class to regex jquery, on index page

Tags: jquery

referring to this question:

[add class to regex jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538476/add-class-to-regex-jquery/9538545)

I would like to know how to use this code for pages like `http://www.mydomain.com` or `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost:3000/` or any index page.

The code example is this for `http://localhost/username/boards`

```
if( /^\/[^/]+\/boards/.test(location.pathname) ) {
     $("#container ul #all_categories a.categories-menu").css("font-weight","bold");
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to do something when the pathname is empty? Test whether it is empty (or contains only `/`) ;)

Comment: Yes when The path name its empty or contain only `/` :D. I have `window.location.href == "http://localhost:3000/"` but it is difficult to maintain :( if I deploy the server in production mode with `http://www.mydomain.com`

Comment: Yeah, so `if(location.pathname === '/')` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, lets make it official:

All you have to do is to test the URL for an empty path:

```
if(location.pathname === '/')
```